# Left Join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Table A` and `Table B`. Both are linked via column `[Project]`.

`Table A` behaves as real customer data. `Table B` is table of all possible values (used for validation).

In other words, a row in `Table A` will have a Project. But in `Table B` this particular Project will have many different varieties ('month', 'year', 'task', 'Organization')

What I want is to join 1-on-1 Table A to Table B and display the [Organization].

The SQL code I am using is:

```
select 
    a.[Amount], a.[project], b.[organization] 
from 
    Table_A as a
left join 
    Table_B as b on a.[Project] = b.[Project]
```

This works, but not 1-on-1. It will duplicate values in Table A to display all values in Table B for each Project.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Screenshot from Table A: In this example, I am using project '4062'..

[image]

Screenshot from Table B (full), with same project - You see all values:

[image]

When I do the Join, this is what I get (added PayID - which is unique in Table A to show duplicates):

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Ok - hang on. I will edit with screenshots.

Comment: Could you share your all colums and simple data ?

Comment: If TableA matches more than one record in TableB for a given project, how do you know which of those record you want?

Comment: Please see screenshots.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Same as screenshot one, but with the extra column [Expenditure Organization]. 1-on-1... I do not want data in Table A to duplicate to match Table B...

Comment: How did you know row from `A` mapper to row `B`?

Comment: Because the project '4062' will always belong to that Organization... No matter what the other values in Table B are...

Comment: Screen shots are a **very bad** way to post sample data. It makes it a lot harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one arbitrary row from `b`, then you can use `outer apply`:

```
select a.[Amount], a.[project], b.[organization]
from Table_A a outer appy
     (select top (1) b.*
      from Table_B b
      where a.[Project] = b.[Project]
     ) b;
```